Using multiple URLS to fetch API JSON Data
I'm currently trying to program a bit of code in Google Apps Script that catalogues item pricing data for an MMORPG by connecting to an API. I've managed to cobble up some code (shown below) that successfully does this for a single item, but I've hit a roadblock with getting it to work for a range of cells in order to cover every item on the spreadsheet.
Essentially, what I need this to do, is grab a series of itemIDs in a defined range (ie. D8:D24), query the API for each of those entries by appending each itemID into the URL, and then properly display it in the adjacent "F" column for each item.
Admittedly I've never coded with JavaScript before and even getting this far took me some learnin'. I think what I might need is a Promise.all() to query the API multiple times and put those results in an array, but I have no clue how to go about that and adapt that to my existing code.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
function getPrices() {
  
  const url = "https://universalis.app/api/v2/world/"

  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Boss Weapons') {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let itemID = [];
    itemID.push(sheet.getRange('D8').getValue());

    let request = url + itemID + "?listings=0&entries=0"
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request);
    let data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    let itemData = [];
    itemData.push(data.minPrice); 
  
    let item = [];
    item.push(itemData);

    let targetRange = sheet.getRange('F8');
    targetRange.setValue(item);
  }
}



Try something like this:
function getPrices() {
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Boss Weapons') {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let ids = sh.getRange("D8:D24").getValues().flat();
    let o = ids.map(id => {
      let request = "https://universalis.app/api/v2/world/" + id + "?listings=0&entries=0"
      let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request);
      let data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      return data;
    })
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o))
  }
}


Thanks for the assistance. I played around with this and this code does seem to work in getting all the needed data from the column of itemIDs. Could I trouble you to also share how to get it to display the needed values on the spreadsheet as well? I tested creating a new async function to handle this using my above code and running getPrices() on an await. but it doesn't post anything. I tried changing setValue to setValues but that just returns an exception saying the number of rows in the data (1) does not meet the number of rows in the range (17).

What does your return data look like?

I put it in a Pastebin https://pastebin.com/31DfSTaG   First 3 itemIDs show how the data is formatted from visiting the URL directly. The rest below it is what the log output looks like, formatted into a large string of keys and values. Not sure how much that matters. Only real value I need from the output is minPrice, and that pasted to range F8:F24 to match where it pulled the itemIDs from.
